# Reshaping the input layer to a single channel and multiple images

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

In some reference code I have picked up, there is:

```
net_->input_blobs()[0]->Reshape(1, 3, height, width);
```

My `prototxt` has:

```
input_shape {
    dim: 1
    dim: 3
    dim: 260
    dim: 347
}
```

I have been indirectly informed that the model provided has been tuned for greyscale (we have both a colour and a greyscale `prototxt`), and the currently-used Python code uses a greyscaled input with three identical channels.

Now I want to do either both or separately process 4 images in a single call to `net_->Forward();` and pass in these four images as one-channel greyscale. So, first, choosing a single channel:

```
net_->input_blobs()[0]->Reshape(1, 1, height, width);
```

What are the repercussions of changing the number of channels? How do all my layers react? Will it work? If it works, will a one-channel net be faster?

Second, choosing four images:

```
net_->input_blobs()[0]->Reshape(4, 3, height, width);
```

I have a feeling that won't work, and I should be looking at increasing the number of `input_blobs`, but how to do that? Or what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. working with a single channel rather than identical three should be faster (fewer multiplication-addition operations). Since this is done at the finest scale, this might even have noticeable impact on run time.
2. Feeding 4 images as a single batch is usually faster than processing each image separately as a batch with one image (due to internal optimization of the computation to work with batches).

Bottom line: you should get better run time running a single batch of four images. If the input is three identical channels - it is better to modify the model to work with only one.

Comment: I'll get in contact with the model developer to see if/how one channel would work. I've read a bit more and `Reshape(4, 3, height, width)` seems to be correct for batching, but can you confirm please?

Comment: Hmm, the output blob after batching is `channels()` of detection results, but I don't see any way to determine which channel corresponds to each input image, as each image can produce multiple results (object detections). Oh well, at least I've learnt some more about Caffe.